# Testing L2 effects without any L2 variance?

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, nested-data, intraclass-correlation

I'm testing a hypothesized effect of an L2 variable on L1 outcomes (students nested in classrooms), but a few of my outcome variables have no L2 (classroom-level) variance (i.e. the within-classroom, student-level variance far outweighs the between-classroom variance, so ICCs are less than .1%).

When I've tried to search this issue, I see lots of sources saying that you don't *NEED* to do multilevel modeling if there's no L2 variance. But I'm wondering if it's still *OK* to do it. Of course there's very little variance to predict, so extremely unlikely to get any appreciable effect (and I have run it and there aren't any). But if I proposed to test these outcomes, should I report the results of the models or just say there wasn't enough variance to run them? Thank you for any thoughts!!